# Where to ask this question about a feature on a web-based application?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am not sure where to ask the question below. So I post it here for directions.

> We are working on a feature on our web application to allow visitors to filter people (human service providers) by age and gender. The question is - would that introduce negative impact of age or gender discrimination? Would that be a concern at all?

Comment: @gnat I'd disagree. This question has nothing to do with programming whatsoever. "Does the presence of an age or gender filter lead to discrimination" is a psychology question more than anything programming-related. I don't see how it benefits from a guide to all the programming-related sites.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid Stack Eccange is not a good place for this question.

Its first impression to me is that it's too broad. It's unlikely to have a specific answer without going too deep in comprehending the question, as there's much too few details provided and answerers have to answer it in every aspect that it covers.

Second, it appears to be opinion-based, which would make it inherently unsuitable on a Stack Exchange site.

There's a *very small* chance that it would be on-topic for Philosophy, but given the points stated above, don't do it. It will be closed as either too broad or opinion-based.

Therefore, I would suggest Quora as a possibly suitable place to ask this question.